# Using try{...}catch(..){...} instead goto

Tags: c++, try-catch, goto

Is it bad practice use try-catch like goto?
For example, simple code

```
try{
    if(argc<2){
        std::cout<<"no inputfile"<<std::endl;
        throw 1;
    }
    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if(FALSE==CreateProcess(argv[1],NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,
                            &cif,&pi)){
        printf("smth is wrong");
        throw 1;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);
    std::cout<<"Process return"<<exitCode<<std::endl;
    throw 1;
}
catch(int a){
    printf("press Enter");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using exceptions for flow control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306913/using-exceptions-for-flow-control)

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to use `goto`, but when you want to use `goto`, camouflaging it as exception handling actually makes it worse.

Comment: See also [Why not use exceptions as regular flow of control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control)

Comment: In this case, if you're looking to "disguise a goto" then `do { ... break; ... } while(false);` is marginally better than `try { ... throw ... throw } catch() {}`. A try block that you *always* exit by throwing runs against the intention. Moving the contents of the `try` block into a function and using `return` to exit early is probably better, and would be enough of a disguise to fool *most* people. The only ones who'd still catch you out are the ones who say a function must only have one `return` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking whether it's wrong to use exceptions for program flow, the answer is *yes, it's wrong*.

That said, for cases where you don't care about performance too much, you can get away with it as long as you don't tell anyone on the internet, and as long as you don't have a production requirement or a long-term maintenance requirement.

In this instance you appear to be using exceptions correctly for everything except the final, successful case.

Comment: -1 because you're wrong, but as an aside, if you felt this question was non constructive enough to close it, then why did you answer it?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Please indicate which part of my answer you disagree with.

Comment: I can't think of anything to use exceptions for *other than* program flow. `try/catch` is a control flow structure. The eternal debate is, what conditions are considered "exceptional enough" to warrant using it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I disagree with the sweeping generalization that: "it's wrong [to use exceptions for program flow]".

Comment: +1 The "eternal debate" has been settled long time ago: exceptions are for exceptional situations.

Comment: @JohnDibling: How is it a "sweeping generalisation" when I spent the entire next paragraph qualifying it?

Comment: Your next paragraph effectively reinforced the first sentence, by casting the idea of exceptions-as-program-flow in such a light so as to suggest that only a non-thinking dolt would use such a construct in real code.  It's a false qualification.

Comment: @JohnDibling: That's your inference, not the implication. I listed concrete examples of when I'd feel free to use such a "pattern" if I felt inclined to (though I should emphasise that this has never occurred in my lifetime). I never used the word "dolt" -- you did.

Answer (score 1):

In general (as in, in a language-agnostic sense, across the board) it is bad practice to use the try / catch mechanism as a control flow management aid. Use it as intended, for managing exceptions. Use control flow constructs to control flow.