# Should I use Try Catch Block to implement my Business Logic?

Tags: c#, java, c++

Suppose I need something like this.( This code is blunder, but just an example). This code is not my problem! Its just an example. I know how to write it using if else statements. I'm  considering a more complicated Context!

```
int[] arraynums = new int[3] {1,2,3};
int Sample = 0;
try
{
Sample = arraynums[3];
}
catch
{
Sample=4;
}
```

Here I can use an alternative logic which wont't run into an error. But still I can reduce the code if I use try catch block. Is it advisable to use a try catch block to solve a logic? If no, then why?

Comment: Three different languages?

Comment: No, address the real problem.

Comment: It's called Exception Driven Development.

Comment: if you're going to do do that at least do `catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)` As it stands you're catching everything.

Comment: Ah so *that's* how people end up with the ingenious try/catch loop design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For following reason you should not use exception to implement business logic (or flow control):

- This is not a good practice. It would confuse the other devs, even you would be confused after 6 month.(This violates the [PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment). This makes it harder for programmers to read.)
- Exception is costly.
- Bad design.

There are fairly good amount of material available in other posts:

- [Using exceptions for flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306913/using-exceptions-for-flow-control)
- [Why not use exceptions as regular flow of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control)

There is whole wiki about it: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Answer (score 3):

Why not using an if-statement?

```
if(arraynums.length > 3)
{
    Sample = arraynums[3];
}
else
{
    Sample = 4;
}
```

Comment: I know it. but  can I use it like that?

Comment: Of course you can use it like that!  Why not try it yourself before asking questions like this?

Comment: Can I use try catch like that?. I knew it could be used like that using if statements. But if I felt that try catch is simpler in a different context, can I use it there to solve the problem?

Comment: @SubinJacob - I think you're confusing **can** and **should**. **can** is on topic for this site, which has been answered, but **should** is off-topic because it'll likely solicit debate. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com for a discussion on design patterns.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your code is fairly contrived, since it's pretty easy to rewrite it without an exception. Exceptions are relatively expensive for the run-time. They can needlessly slow down your code if abused. In general, you should check for exceptional conditions before you allow them to be thrown.

Recommended reading:

- [Using Exceptions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173161.aspx)
- [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 I hate it when I see code that throws only to unwind the stack. It's usually a sign of bad design. Yes, you technically can do that, but **should** is another issue...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would only ever use a try catch for errors or in circumstances where you are not sure whether the object will be available at run time.

In your code you might be better off setting Sample = 4 as a default and doing a check before setting it to arraynums[3].