# NullPointerException is not being caught in try block

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception, log4j, double

The following code to try to catch a `NullPointerException` via logging is not working. Can someone please look at this and guide me.

```
try {
    if (results1 != 00.00) {
        throw new Exception("Data must be added");
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {  
    log.error("You have an error", e);
}
```

The user must enter a value for results1 as it is used for a calculation. Results1 is a double as it is a percentage, I am willing to change it to an int if thats what it takes to make it work. I also want to check through the try and catch technique if a user accidently added a % sign. I want  my logger to catche the NumberFormatException for testing purposes.

UPDATE: Ok thanks for the feedback ( I somehow overlooked that). It still doesn't work. I think this might be the problem:

```
          (results1 != 00.00)
```

Is this the best way to check if the input is empty for a double. Also How can i check if a string is added?

Comment: Why are throwing `NullPointerException` for `results1 != 00.00`!This doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should create a new question for your edited part. Accept one of the answers to the current question.

Comment: Whoa, the question has been changed considerably, hence the old answers don't make sense any more.

Comment: Is nobody going to point out that using exceptions for control flow is a bad idea? Also: if result1 is a double it can never cause a NumberFormatException or a NullPointerException. Please show more of your code and explain what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: This code cannot possibly throw a `NullPointerException`, so of course it isn't being caught. @AdriaanKoster Exceptions *are* a form of flow control.

Comment: @EJP That's true, but they are supposed to be used for _exceptional_ cases that cannot be handled at the level in the callstack where they occur. In this example an exception is used where a regular control mechanism would suffice, which is bad practice. See also this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306913/using-exceptions-for-flow-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullPointerExeption` isn't an instance of `NumberFormatException` thus it wasnt caught.

You should catch common ancestor of those two, here are the docs: [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) and  [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). But from my point of view it's better to throw `IllegalArgumentException` and handle that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` is not an `instanceof` `NumberFormatException`. You need to catch the correct exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to this it should work:

```
try {
   if (results1 != 00.00 ) { 
    throw new Exception("Data must be added"); 
   }
} catch (Exception e)   {  
   log.error("You have an error", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the null pointer exception as another catch block. Null pointer exception is not an instance of Numberformat exception

Answer (score 0):

You should catch NullPointerException instead of NumberFormatException.