# Why does it show "possible null reference" warning when I have handled the ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, exception, nullable

The exact warning I get is

> Possible null reference argument for parameter 's' in 'double double.Parse(string s)

```
try
{
    // this is the line where it shows the warning as `input` can be null:
    double grade = double.Parse(input);

    book.AddGrade(grade);
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Isn't the `ArgumentNullException` that the parse function can throw comes under the `ArgumentException` and thus should be handled?

Also I know `TryParse` can also be used but as a complete beginner I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306913/using-exceptions-for-flow-control is explanation of what you are doing (in case you did not know the name)

Comment: It's telling you that `input` might be `null` when it reaches that point.

Comment: A double cannot be null, but that `book` or `input` probably can

Comment: This seems like a recoverable error. I would suggest using `double.TryParse()` instead and write code to handle the issue with the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# compiler produces warning at that line because argument of `Parse` is marked as "non-nullable" and the compiler determined that the parameter `input` you are passing to that call can be null at the point of call. Compiler does not consider exception handling as a way to "safely handling null arguments" - instead it tries to guide you to avoid exceptions in a first place.

In this particular case it looks like you expect non-parseable values to be in `input` there is specific method - `TryParse` that makes handling of all invalid inputs (including `null`) uniform (returning false). In other cases you should either handle null values explicitly or review and potentially adjust the preceding/calling code to make it clear to the compiler (and more importantly to human readers of the code) that null can't reach the line in question.

Side note: generally, [Using exceptions for flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306913/using-exceptions-for-flow-control) (which is what the code shown in the post doing) considered anti-pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read the post you linked but I still have a bit trouble in understanding what exactly do you mean when you say using exceptions for flow control and how exceptions should be used in the first place. From what I was able to gather though, instead of expecting exceptions and dealing with them , I should try to avoid them in the first place (like you mentioned here)